# Upgrading from jquery 1.8.2 to 1.11.2 will raise the following error :- "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property '_renderItem'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i use to have jQuery 1.8.2 and jquery-ui 1.8.2 and the below script was working well:-

```
  $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"), minLength: 1, delay: 1000,

            create: function () {
                $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    if (!item.extra)
                    {
                        return $('<li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a>' + '<b>' + item.label + '</b></a>')
                                                           .appendTo(ul);

                    }
                    return $('<li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a>' + '<b>' + item.label + '</b>     "<span class="autocompleteResult">' + item.status + ' <li class=" icon-arrow-right"></li> ' + item.techtype + '</span>"<br>' + '<span class="autocompleteResult">' + item.resourcename + '<span class="autocompleteResultSeperator"> | </span>' + item.customername + '<span class="autocompleteResultSeperator"> | </span>' + item.sitename + '<hr style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">' + '</span></a>')
                                    .appendTo(ul);
                };
            }
        });

    });
```

But now i have upgraded the jquery from 1.8.2 to 1.11.2 , and i start receiving the following exception :-

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property
>   '_renderItem' of undefined or null reference

can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After upgrade, you should retrieve the instance widget with `$(this).data("ui-autocomplete")`, instead of `$(this).data("autocomplete")`. In other words, using `ui-` prefix with the name of the widget is imperative.

Alternatively, one can use `instance` method, like this:

```
$(this).autocomplete('instance')._renderItem = //...
```

Comment: you mean the problem is with this line of code :- "var target = $(this);" ?

Comment: No, it's about retrieving the instance of the _widget_.